docker pull manifest unknown: manifest unknown
I'm using docker registry, using minio to store images.
Here's what my registry is configured to do and the command to run it
# vim /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  delete:
    enabled: true
  s3:
    accesskey: admin
    secretkey: adminadmin
    region: us-east-1
    regionendpoint: http://192.168.44.100:9000
    bucket: registry
    encrypt: false
    secure: false
    v4auth: true
    chunksize: 5242880
    rootdirectory: /
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3

docker run -d -p 1080:5000 \
  -v /etc/docker/registry:/etc/docker/registry \
  -v /data/pass/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  --restart always \
  --name=registry registry:2.8.3

I uploaded some mirrors to the registry, but there seems to be a problem when I pull it up;
docker pull 192.168.44.100:1080/stress:0.2
Error response from daemon: manifest for 192.168.44.100:1080/stress:0.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

The docker image does exist
curl -XGET http://192.168.44.100:1080/v2/stress/tags/list
{"name":"stress","tags":["0.2"]}

curl 'http://192.168.44.135:1080/v2/_catalog'
{"repositories":["nginx","stress","testcentos"]}

Contents of docker image in minio
I don't know what's wrong, before I deleted all the data from the registry bucket in minio and repushed it, docker pull was working without any problems, but after that I run docker pull and get the problem shown in the title
Looking forward to your help!
